# Express, Passport and sequelize crash when try to save data

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

I create a simple 0auth2 server, based on [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/master/README.md) , Express.js and Sequelize. 
I would like to register users, and save them into database. 
But when I call function from sequelize to store data into, my app crash. 
I get 404 messages, and my user is not saved into db. 
I use postman to do the request. 
If I comment the `add` function, my app works

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
require("./config/passport");
const routes = require("./routes/routes");
const db = require('./config/database');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {  
});

app.use(passport.initialize());

var corsOptions = { 
allowedHeaders: ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Authorization'],
methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'],
optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
origin: '*'
 }
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use("/", routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
console.log(err) ;
next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Route.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const authentication = require ("../controller/authentication");
const auth2 = require("../controller/0auth2");

router.post('/login', authentication.login);
router.post('/register',authentication.register);
module.exports = router;
```

Authentication.js

```
module.exports.register = function(req, res) {
passport.authenticate("local-signup", function(err, user, info, email_token) {
if (err) {
  res.status(404).json(err);
  return;
}
if (user)
{
        res.status(200);
    res.json({user : user,
});
    }
    else{
        res.status(200);
    res.json(info);
            }
})(req, res);
};
```

Passport.js

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField : 'username',
passwordField : 'password',
passReqToCallback : true
  }, function(req, username, password, done) { 
    Users.add()
    .then(() => {
var newUserMysql = {
     username: username,
     email: req.body.email,
     password: "test"
     };
return done(null, newUserMysql);
});
```

})
    );

Query.js

```
module.exports = {
 add: function() {
//POST
return Users.create({
username: 'allo',
email: 'allo',
password: 'allo'
})
.then(user => {
 //res.json(user);
console.log("test");
})
.catch(error => { 
console.log("allo");
//res.status(400).send(error);
 })
}
};
```

Model.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

const Model = Sequelize.Model; 

class Users extends Model {}
Users.init({
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
    permission: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    isActive: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'users' });
}
```

Database.js

```
const env = require('./env');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 

const sequelize = new Sequelize(env.database, env.username,    env.password, { 
 host: env.host,
dialect: env.dialect,
pool: {
max: env.max,
min: env.pool.min,
acquire: env.pool.acquire,
idle: env.pool.idle
}
});
const db = {}; 
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.users = require("./models/users"). (sequelize, Sequelize);
    db.clients = require("./models/clients.js")(sequelize, Sequelize); 

module.exports = db;
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this

```
var User = require('./models/user');

app.use(require("express-session")({
  secret:"THIS IS SECRET",
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
}); 

app.get("/register",function(req,res){
  res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register",function(req,res){
  var newUser  = new User({username:req.body.username,email:req.body.email});
  var password = req.body.password; 

  User.register(newUser, password, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);

    } else{
       passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
       res.redirect("/");
    });
    }
  });
});



///////////////////////////log in/////////////////////////////////
app.get("/login",function(req,res){
  res.render("login");
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",{
  successRedirect:"/",
  failureRedirect:"/login"
}), function(req,res){
});
```

**User model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
 var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username:String,
   password:String,
   email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},

 });

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

Comment: I try ```User.register(newUser, password, function(err, user){ if(err){ console.log(err); } else{ passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){ res.redirect("/"); });``` but still have issue

Comment: did you take the input value using body parser ?  ```var newUser  = new User({username:req.body.username,email:req.body.email});
  var password = req.body.password; ``` first you have to create newUser. check my ```/register```  it will create new user.  If user is already created then  ```/login``` function if every thing is wroking fine it will create and also redirect

Comment: It is only for development. The issue is from sequelize. When I success to call sequelize function, I improve the function with parameters